# Checking for references

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference

I have an external .js script.  I want it to do one thing if the html file using it is referencing jQuery, and do another if it doesn't.  is this possible?  Can I reference jQuery from my script to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the global `jQuery` object is defined:

```
if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") {
    alert("jQuery not present"); 
}
else {
    alert("jQuery present"); 
}
```

You can read up on dynamic script inclusion [here](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html).